# Layout Route does not work as expected with react-router-dom@6

Tags: reactjs, layout, react-router-dom

I am working with react-router-dom@6.2.
When trying to wrap my elements with "DefaultLayout" element manually everything seems to be OK:

```
<Route path="/privacy" element={<PageLayout><Privacy /></PageLayout>} />
<Route path="/tos" element={<PageLayout><Tos /></PageLayout>} />
```

However, when trying to use:

```
<Route element={<PageLayout />}>
    <Route path="/privacy" element={<Privacy />} />
    <Route path="/tos" element={<Tos />} />
</Route>
```

I only get the header and the footer without the "children" elements.
What might be the reason?

Answer (score 4):

OK. Problem solved.
The Layout page should render `<Outlet />` element for this to work.
This is how it looks like:

** DefaultLayout **

```
import React from "react";
import { Header } from "./partials/Header";
import { Footer } from "./partials/Footer";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export const DefaultLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="default-layout">
      <header className="header">
        <Header />
      </header>
      <main className="main">
        <Outlet />
      </main>
      <footer className="footer">
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

** app.js **

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { DefaultLayout } from "./components/layout/DefaultLayout";
import { AddTicket } from "./pages/add-ticket/AddTicket";
import { Dashboard } from "./pages/dashboard/Dashboard";
import { Entry } from "./pages/entry/Entry";
import { TicketList } from "./pages/ticket-list/TicketList";
import { Ticket } from "./pages/ticket/Ticket";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Entry />} />
        <Route element={<DefaultLayout />}>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="/tickets" element={<TicketList />} />
          <Route path="/ticket" element={<Ticket />} />
          <Route path="/add-ticket" element={<AddTicket />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: To be clear, the layout route component needs to render the <Outlet /> component from react-router-dom.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrap your code with `<Routes>` like that:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<PageLayout />}>
  <Route path="/privacy" element={<Privacy />} />
  <Route path="/tos" element={<Tos />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

---

**index.js** here You have example from [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/installation) how to use react-router-dom@v6

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.js**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to React Router!</h1>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
However, my code is wrapped with <Routes> already. 
I think it wouldn't have worked even manually without <Routes>.

Comment: Okay  I've tried my best ,for the future, try to add as much info as possible  ;-)

Comment: Sure. Thanks :-)